# 3d city website. Morden technologies

Tags: browser, 3d

Any ideas how to create 3d graphics in a web browser.
I want to create a simle 3d model of my city.

I know about google earth but I want my own website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should Morden be Modern?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [O3D](http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/) or [Flash 10](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/).  Both require your users to install an add-on.

Comment: Do o3d libraries support skatchup models?

Comment: The first hit when I search google for "o3d sketchup" seems to indicate it is possible.  Are you even trying?
http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/docs/sketchupmodels.html

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Java applet using Java3D (one possibility).  See http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/.  You'd pretty much be starting from scratch though.  If there's any way that the Google Earth could meet your needs, that would probably be your best bet.